# How to get rid of duplicating data in every row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
        SELECT distinct AD.ReferenceNumber, AD.ProjectTitle, Z.ZoneCode, C.CompanyName,SS.AssignedTo, ZG.ZoneGroupName,au.Amount
        FROM ApplicationDetails AD
        LEFT JOIN ApplicationFormsDetails AS b ON (AD.referencenumber = b.referencenumber)
        LEFT JOIN ScheduleSummaries AS SS ON (AD.ReferenceNumber = SS.ReferenceNo)
        INNER JOIN AppTypes as at on ss.ItemCode = at.Category
        INNER JOIN Companies AS C ON (AD.CompanyId = C.CompanyID)
        INNER JOIN Zones Z ON (C.ZoneCode = Z.ZoneCode)
        INNER JOIN ZoneGroups ZG ON (Z.ZoneGroup = ZG.ZoneGroupId)
        LEFT JOIN AssessmentUsedItems au on ah.AssessmentHeaderId = au.HeaderId
        WHERE AD.ApplicationDate BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31' AND ZG.ZoneGroupCode = 'HO' and ah.referencenumber = 'N-101317-A1-02'
        GROUP BY AD.ReferenceNumber, AD.ProjectTitle, Z.ZoneCode, C.CompanyName,SS.AssignedTo, ZG.ZoneGroupName,au.Amount--, ah.ApplicationForm,au.Amount
```

The output of this query is its duplicating the amount for every AssignTO.

Output :

[image]

Comment: edit the question add some sample data & desired result would really help.

Comment: Furthermore provide a definition of "duplicate"! Which columns are your key? Technically a distinct filters duplicates, so at least one or more columns should be differing in your example. Besides, the group by should be enough. Maybe you want to try using "sum(au.amount)" instead of "au.amount" and remove au.amount from the group by as well...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try using `SUM(ISNULL(au.amount, 0)) AS amount` instead of `au.amount` and remove `au.amount` from the `GROUP BY` as well...

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT AD.ReferenceNumber,
       AD.ProjectTitle,
       Z.ZoneCode,
       C.CompanyName,
       SS.AssignedTo,
       ZG.ZoneGroupName,
       SUM(COALESCE(au.Amount,0)) AS Amount
FROM   ApplicationDetails AD
       LEFT JOIN ApplicationFormsDetails  AS b
            ON  (AD.referencenumber = b.referencenumber)
       LEFT JOIN ScheduleSummaries        AS SS
            ON  (AD.ReferenceNumber = SS.ReferenceNo)
       INNER JOIN AppTypes                AS at
            ON  ss.ItemCode = at.Category
       INNER JOIN Companies               AS C
            ON  (AD.CompanyId = C.CompanyID)
       INNER JOIN Zones Z
            ON  (C.ZoneCode = Z.ZoneCode)
       INNER JOIN ZoneGroups ZG
            ON  (Z.ZoneGroup = ZG.ZoneGroupId)
       LEFT JOIN AssessmentUsedItems au
            ON  ah.AssessmentHeaderId = au.HeaderId
WHERE  AD.ApplicationDate BETWEEN '2017-10-01' AND '2017-10-31'
       AND ZG.ZoneGroupCode = 'HO'
       AND ah.referencenumber = 'N-101317-A1-02'
GROUP BY
       AD.ReferenceNumber,
       AD.ProjectTitle,
       Z.ZoneCode,
       C.CompanyName,
       SS.AssignedTo,
       ZG.ZoneGroupName
```

Comment: Looks pretty much like my suggestion :-)